# Possible to run Windows Phone 8 Emulator in AZURE VM?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, virtual-machine

Does anyone know what are the steps necessary to run Windows Phone 8 Emulator in an Azure VM? I can't seem to add the Hyper V role which the Emulator complains that it needs. Is this even possible?

Comment: I am really interested in knowing why would you want that... :)

Comment: To answer the question of "why would you want that" - Dev&Test scenario with MSDN sub!

Comment: As @astaykov alluded to. I'm using azure as a virtualized development environment. I tried to then run Windows Phone 8 emulator from Visual Studio, and BAM, errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No!

Unfortunately you can't! The issue with the fact that the WP8 Emulator needs and uses Hyper-V. And in Windows Azure we are already virtualized. So simple rule:

> You can't virtualize what is already virtualize

This is the same as you can't install Hyper-V role on a Windows Server which runs inside Hyper-V already. So, no solution to your question at all.

Comment: So thats a flat no then for all WP8 development needs on an Azure VM? As the Emulator is a pretty critical part of the development experience.

Comment: tell me about it. I generally hate the idea that WP Emulator wants to enable Hyper-V on my machine and mess with my network adapters :S

Comment: No, you can run a virtualized system inside of another virtualized system on any modern hypervisor and x86 CPU without any significant performance degradation. It's just nested virtualization is not enabled on Azure.

Comment: Acually, it is now possible to use nested VMs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for updating.