# Is there any way, that I can make Android Emulator run on Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, android-emulator, azure-virtual-machine

I installed Android Studio on Azure VM and installed all the prerequisites. When I try to run the emulator, I get the following error

[image]

When I try to install HAXM, I get the following error:

[image]

I checked that my Azure VM runs on AMD Processor. Is there any way, that I can make Android Emulator run on Azure Virtual Machine?

Comment: I’m looking for something like this for the Google Android Enulator images: http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/blog/android-azure-emulator.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something that requires virtualization isn't going to run in an Azure VM (which is already virtualized). Same thing with, say, WP8 emulator (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009977/possible-to-run-windows-phone-8-emulator-in-azure-vm) question, with the same answer).

**EDIT** - As of mid-2017, there are now VMs that support nested virtualization (Dv3 and Ev3 series, for now). See [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization) for more information.

Comment: does this change with windows server 2016?

Comment: What about creating Azure VM with Android VM? Is that completely crazy or worth trying?

Comment: To be more specific, you can't run Android emulators because nested virtualization is not enabled on Azure. Other than that, it is perfectly normal to run a virtualized system inside of another virtualized system on any modern hypervisor and x86 CPU without any significant performance degradation.

Answer (score 2):

The Android emulator works with the following setup:

Azure VM: Windows 10 Enterprise N

Android Studio: 2.3.1

AVD Manager

```
Hardware: Phone -> Nexus 5X
System Image: Other Images -> Nougat 25 armeabi-v7a [Android 7.1.1]
```

Start the emulator and wait about 5-10 minutes for the process to complete.
Then run your Android app by attaching it to the running emulator.
Note that "Apply Changes" (lightning bolt icon) also works for small code changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the CPU of the emulator to armeabi-v7a it will work (albeit very very slowly). Tested with Rev 25. I assume this works because it doesn't use virtualization, but rather CPU Emulation.

Answer (score 0):

As of mid-2017, there are now VMs that support [nested virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization) (Dv3 and Ev3 series, for now). Still, I couldn't run the Android virtual device(AVD) created in the android studio. But, below solution worked for me:

1. Check if Azure VM supports nested virtualization.
2. Enable hyper-v in VM as mentioned here [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization).
3. Use [Visual Studio Emulator](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/). Visual studio emulator definitely works on azure VM.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about enabling nested virtualization or else.
All you have to do is:

1. Disable Hyper-V
2. Install Mumu emulator.

And you'll see emulator working on your VM.