# Emulator not opening from Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, hyper-v

I am trying to develop an Android app using Xamarin.Android (Visual Studio 2017) for which a emulator is much necessary. I am using Visual studio for Andriod to get the emulators. Recently, I had downloaded Emulator (API Level 23) and try to launch it. Unfortunately I am facing the following error:

> The emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running: 
>   Something happened while starting a virtual machine: 'VS Emulator 5.1-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXHDPI Phone.lalith.varanasi' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID FFBA563C-F643-491F-89C2-753EC3E061D6) 
>   The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'VS Emulator 5.1-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXHDPI Phone.lalith.varanasi' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID FFBA563C-F643-491F-89C2-753EC3E061D6).

I am using a VM hosted on Micorsoft Azure. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

In order to add a physical Android device as an emulator I cannot find a way to connect my android phone to VM which I connect.

Any alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way, that I can make Android Emulator run on Azure Virtual Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191202/is-there-any-way-that-i-can-make-android-emulator-run-on-azure-virtual-machine)

Comment: Often you need to download Android Studio and use their Emulator Manager to edit the individual aspects of your VMs... that way you can have much more control over the settings and reset/update them as needed.