# Bluestacks in VM Azure

Tags: azure, android-emulator, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I need Install Bluestacks (Android Emulator) on my VM Azure But This Program need Virtualization Technology (enable VT Engine).
I Get This Error Every Time :[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e0ou.jpg)

and my Hyper-v is Disable that its ok(because must be inactive according to error) :[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVTVE.jpg)

how can I Enable VT in my VM Azure?
in the regular PC We need to Go the Bios Setting(When PC restart we Press For Example F2) But in VM Azure How Can Do it?

This instruction that i found in the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

do you think this is related to my question, is this instruction enable VT ?
[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jq3o.jpg)

IF YES. So I created Vm with size(Standard D2 v3)
According to that instruction requirements, Do I Have All Prerequisites?

And in Part 2 : I must run Command "Set-VMProcessor....."
but I don't know if I do it right?

it say : "While the virtual machine is in the OFF state, run the following command on the physical Hyper-V host."
it means I Press Stop on Vm ? Then run in powershell ?
[Image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3GTn.jpg)

in code we see two part that include "VMName"
Should I change it to the name I chose for the VM?
Or I have to copy and run the code without changing it.
I tested them all but it gave me errors every time.
[Image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpqjT.jpg)

how can I Enable VT in my VM Azure?

Thank you for Reading my Question

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but assuming I understand you correctly, I don't think Azure allows for configuration of a physical host. If you're trying to install it on a VM *inside* your VM, then I would say "nested virtualization" applies. However, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by doing it; clarifying that will get you better help.

Answer (score 0):

Your linking document is about physical Hyper-V host. In this case, you can learn from [How to enable nested virtualization in an Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization). First of all, you need a nesting capable Azure VM. For example, you can select Dv3 or Ev3 series virtual machines.

Secondly, you can RDP to your Azure VM and enable the Hyper-V feature and Management Tools. The Azure VM will restart.

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
```

Refer to more [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191202/is-there-any-way-that-i-can-make-android-emulator-run-on-azure-virtual-machine).